# sending empty buffer from client to server

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, server, client

I am trying to send file from client to server. I read line by line and send it to server. When the line is empty, after I call `send()` function in client for sending the buffer (empty line) my client side is waiting for the response from server, and and the server doesn't send anything. As a result, all program is on halt.

I try to use Wireshark, but the line is empty so I don't see anything. I try to add if `line.empty()` function, and with that i ignore the empty line.

## client side

```
  while(!fichier.eof()) {
// On le lis ligne par ligne

      //ligne2+=ligne1;

         // cout << "********lu ******** " <<ligne2<<endl;  
                  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));//clear the buffer
                  cout << "********lu et copy dans msg ******** " <<endl; 
                  getline(fichier,ligne1);
                  cout << "********lign "<<ligne1<<endl; 
                 // strcpy(msg, ligne1.c_str());

                     // if (!ligne1.empty()) {
                 // strcpy(msg, dt.c_str());
                  cout << "********envoi au serv************** "<<endl; 
                  //bytesWritten += send(clientSd, (char*)&msg, strlen(msg), 0); 
                    bytesWritten += send(clientSd, ligne1.data(),ligne1.size(), 0); 
                            cout << "********bytesWritten "<<bytesWritten<<endl;
                  cout << "********attente ************** "<<endl; 
                  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));//clear the buffer
              bytesRead += recv(clientSd, (char*)&msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
                   cout << "********msg "<<msg<<endl; 
                  cout << "Server: " << msg << endl;
                      //  }
```

## server side

```
  //of the data read  

                buffer[valread] = '\0';  
                ////////////////receiving file ///////////////////////
         /* ofstream flux("fichier.txt");
                  flux.seekp(0,ios::end);
                  flux << buffer << endl;*/
                  std::ofstream outfile;
          outfile.open("fichier.txt", std::ios_base::app);
          outfile <<buffer; 
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
                string data="bien reçu";
        //getline(cin, data);
        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); //clear the buffer
        strcpy(buffer, data.c_str());

                send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );  
                memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); //clear the buffer 
               // bytesWritten += send(sd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

I want to send file even if the file contains empty line, and receiving the response from server.

Comment: Impossible. There is no such thing as an empty buffer in TCP. If you send zero bytes, nothing happens on the wire, and the receiver sees nothing.

Comment: why didn't you try using start packet which sends file len

Comment: Either you send a specific string to notify the buffer is empty (or a single value) or you set a timeout on the server's side (if the timeout is reached, then you can consider that either the buffer is empty or an error occurred and nothing could be sent). I do prefer the first solution.

Comment: You can't 'send a specific string' unless you take steps to ensure that if that string occurs in the data it is distinguished. What you need here is an application protocol. @Fareanor

Comment: You need to define a protocol for communication.   That protocol needs to specify some way of sending some data that means "sending no data"

Comment: @user207421 Yes of course, by "specific string" I meant something that is exclusive to an implied communication protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an empty buffer because... there's nothing to send.

But I think an elegant solution could be to prepend a header to your data that is the length of the buffer.
If you receive a positive value followed by some data, then the value is the data's length. If you receive zero followed by nothing, then it means that the buffer was empty.

Comment: thanks for your respond finally i just  read line and check if it is empty or not and after i send to the server if it is not empty

Comment: @Thierno That would make the received file look different from the original file.

Comment: yes, i notice that so what is the best way to do if i want to copy file that contains empty line.

Comment: @Thierno A newline is created with the character `'\n'`. So when you have two consecutive `'\n'` then you have an empty line. On some platforms (Windows for example), the newline character is prepended by a carriage return so that becomes `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Remember that "empty" is a word which does not have meaning here. In memory, there always is a value, reserved or free. In a file, this is the same thing, it's a sequence of bytes, an empty line is only visually empty but you have to write something to say "ok, here is an empty line". This is what `'\n'` does. But strictly speaking, there is no empty spaces whether in memory or in a hard disk.